# How to insert new rows and values for each ID in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, retain

I have 3 variables: ID, days and temperature. For each entry,I need to insert rows of additional days for each ID and I need the temperature to carry over among those rows.

The goal is to have each ID have complete continuous days that have the same temperature. This is what I have:

```
ID             day               temp 
1001            68                16
1001            73                14
1002            85                17
1002            89                15
1003            91                18
1004            97                19
1004            99                20
1004           106                12
1005           109                15
1006           111                18
1006           115                19
1006           120                20
1006           122                21
```

And here's what I want:

```
ID             day               temp 
1001            68                16
1001            69                16
1001            70                16
1001            71                16
1001            72                16
1001            73                14
1001            74                14
1001            75                14
1001            76                14
1001            77                14
1001            78                14
1001            79                14
1001            80                14
1001            81                14
1001            82                14
1001            83                14
1001            84                14
1002            85                17
1002            86                17
1002            87                17
1002            88                17
1002            89                15
1002            90                15
1003            91                18
1003            92                18
1003            93                18
1003            94                18
1003            95                18
1003            96                18
1004            97                19
1004            98                19
1004            99                19
```

```
proc sort data=have;
by ID;
run;

data want;
set have;
retain temp ID;
day=day +1;
if first.day then temp= temp+0;
end;
run;
```

i expect the results to be like this:

```
ID             day               temp 
1001            68                16
1001            69                16
1001            70                16
1001            71                16
1001            72                16
1001            73                14
1001            74                14
1001            75                14
1001            76                14
1001            77                14
1001            78                14
1001            79                14
1001            80                14
1001            81                14
1001            82                14
1001            83                14
1001            84                14
1002            85                17
1002            86                17
1002            87                17
1002            88                17
1002            89                15
1002            90                15
1003            91                18
1003            92                18
1003            93                18
1003            94                18
1003            95                18
1003            96                18
1004            97                19
1004            98                19
1004            99                19
```

but somehow i am still getting the old data that I am trying to change. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are essentially modifying the record instead of inserting multiple records in between two records. You also have syntax errors. See my answer for one possible way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: For climate data, the assumption that LOCF is not appropriate for filling in missing data. I'm hoping this is a generated use case.

Comment: Why would extend ID=1001 records from its last date to the first date for the next ID?  That doesn't make sense.  What does ID mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should get you what you want except the last entry which seems inconsistent with your logic:

```
1004            99                19
```

It comes out to be:

```
1004            99                20
```

based on your logic.

```
proc sort data=have;
by ID day;
run;

data want;
 merge have have (firstobs=2 rename=(id=id2 day=day2 temp=temp2));

 output;

 if (day2 > day) then do;
   do while (day < day2 - 1);
     day + 1; output;
   end;
 end;

 keep id day temp;
run;
```

Comment: This works. Thanks so much for your response. And you are right it should be 20 at the end. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A robust solution would reset the iteration at the start of each `id` group.  Your sample data does not exhibit the case of a successive group having a start day earlier than the prior group.  Without testing for the start of an id group (or being within the group) the result may not be as expected.

Example with self 1:1 merge with second self starting at `obs=2` to provide *lead* values from *next* row. Data was amended with groups `id=1007` and `id=1009` such that a *reset* is necessary.  The group *within-ness* condition is tested with `id=lead_id`

```
data have; input
ID     day  temp; datalines;
1001    68   16
1001    73   14
1002    85   17
1002    89   15
1003    91   18
1004    97   19
1004    99   20
1004   106   12
1005   109   15
1006   111   18
1006   115   19
1006   120   20
1006   122   21
1007     1    1
1007    15    0
1007    16    2
1007    20    5
1008    35   12
1008    37   14
1008    45   20
run;

data want (drop=lead:);
  merge have have(keep=day id rename=(id=lead_id day=lead_day) firstobs=2);
  * by is not used for a 1:1 merge;

  if id=lag(id) and day < lag(day) then do;
    put "ERR" "OR: Stopping because days are not ordered within " ID= "at " day= ;
    stop;
  end;    

  if (id=lead_id) then do day=day to lead_day-1;
    output; * fill-in rows with same temp;
  end;
  else 
    output; * final row of group;
run;
```

Comment: And here I was thinking I was the only person that splits out the string `ERROR:` in my code. =)

Comment: Haha, I got that from you!  Sure helps when searching the log for actual `ERROR:`

Comment: Nice! Glad I could give something back... I've stolen a lot of your macros over the years...